# I'm having an issue with the delimiters in this java code?

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is have this code ask for 2 integer inputs, read data from a file called 'temps.txt', and output the number of days processed, along with the average temperature processed. The problem is I'm getting this error

```
Input the maximum temperature.
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at TempReader.main(TempReader.java:15)
You did not input a valid integer.
```

whenever I try to run it. So far my code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;


public class TempReader{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File myFile = new File("temps.txt");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile).useDelimiter(",");

while (true){

    System.out.println("Input the maximum temperature.");

try {
            int maxTemp = input.nextInt();

    }
    catch (Throwable t) {

        t.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("You did not input a valid integer.");
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Input the minimum temperature.");
    try {
        int minTemp = input.nextInt();

    }
    catch (Throwable t) {

        t.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("You did not input a valid integer.");
        break;
    }
}


}

}
```

And the temps txt file looks like this

04/01/2013,10

04/02/2013,20

04/03/2013,30

04/04/2013,40

04/05/2013,50

04/06/2013,60

I've tried using both / and , as delimiters, and neither works, is it possible to have 2 of them, or am I going to have to do something else?

(Yes, I can make it do the processes I mentioned above, all I need help with is this error, as I don't know whats causing it)

Comment: it is pretty clear what is causing it `line 15`, which ever line that may be. did it ever dawn on you to print out the input that line is trying to process to see why it isn't an `int`?

Comment: It seems like the input.nextInt() is hitting the / and is unable to process it. Reevaluate your parsing scheme. Consider using a delimiter. Find something in the text that separates entries.

Comment: I added the / as the delimiter instead of the comma, and now it's giving me this: Input the maximum temperature.
Input the minimum temperature.
Input the maximum temperature.
java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
 at TempReader.main(TempReader.java:16)
You did not input a valid integer.

Comment: Is it possible to have two delimiters?

Comment: Your title is the first thing that attracts experts to your question. As it stands your title could apply to tens of thousands of questions. Try to make it a little more specific

Comment: @Jeff Gibbs - Yes it possible to have multiple delimiters in the form of `Pattern`. In you case it seems to be **",|\/"** for comma and slash or **"\n|\/"** for new line and slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File myFile = new File("C:/temps.txt");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile);
        String linrread = null;
        try {
            while ((linrread = input.nextLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("linrread ."+ linrread);
                if (linrread.indexOf(",") != -1) {
                    String[] split = linrread.split(",");
                    String date = split[0];
                    String temp = split[1];
                    System.out.println("date :" + date + " temp: " + temp);
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Reached end of the file.");
        }

    }
```

this code will read your file and get the elements from the file. you have to modify this to fit into your requirement.

Comment: gives me this error: cannot find symbol class NoSuchElementException

Comment: `import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;`

Answer (score 1):

Check your data file and what you are trying to read.

`04/01/2013` is not an integer!

**UPDATE**

Use `Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse(input.next());` to get your date THEN get your temperature with `nextInt`. Also, you seem to be looking for max AND min temps in the file, but there is only one temp per day. Your attempt to read min temp will always throw an exception because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @JeffGibbs read a `String` through `nextLine()`, then use the `split("/")` function to split the `String` from `nextLine()` into three `String`s: "04", "01", "2013".

Comment: `Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse(input.next());` (assuming month before day, otherwise reverse the format of day/month)

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about `Scanner`, but I know about the old-fashioned way of doing this, and, more importantly, I know how to make it work. Here's the code:

```
public class TempReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File myFile = new File("temps.txt");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
            System.out.println("Input the maximum temperature.");
            try {
                int maxTemp = Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("You did not input a valid integer.");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Input the minimum temperature.");
            try {
                int minTemp = Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("You did not input a valid integer.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a straightforward modification of your program, with `BufferedReader`, `StringTokenizer`, and `Integer.parseInt` used in place of `Scanner`, which I could never understand that well.

Comment: It's saying it can't find the symbols for any of these? Like IOException, BufferedReader, FileReader, etc. Do I need to import something?

Comment: Yes. They are all in the `java.io` package, so if you `import java.io.*` it will work. I usually forgo putting imports in my sample code, because they take up space and time and can be deduced by any good programmer.

Comment: Ahh, well i'm a noobie. I typed it in, but now it's expecting an identifier and a semicolon?

Comment: it reports it on line 1

Comment: Well, there is a better answer above. Take a look at it.